# How do I write a jquery js.erb to have both html and ruby output for a link_to :remote => in rails 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my js.erb file, but it doesn't execute the ruby code:

```
4 //Update the number of followers
  5 $('.follow-count').html("#{@followers_count} following")
```

What's the right way to mix both ruby (and access things from the controller) and regular text?

Comment: $('.follow-count').html("<%= #{@followers_count} %> following")

Comment: @Angela: Syed and Dylan answers is sufficient to your question..:):):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js.erb` files work just like your `html.erb` files. You need to use `<%= %>` tags instead:

```
 $('.follow-count').html("<%= @followers_count %> following")
```